# How can i display swf file in asp.net flash control?

Tags: asp.net

I have used asp.net flash control to display flash file in asp.net, but it doesnt work for me.

Here is the code I used:

```
<ASPNetFlash:Flash ID="Flash1" runat="server" PlayerVersionAutoDetect="true"    
                                                  MovieURL="flash/cube.swf">
     <HTMLAlternativeTemplate>
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButtonGetFlashPlayer" runat="server"     PostBackUrl="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer" ImageUrl="http://www.aspnetflash.com/images/get_flash_player.gif" />
     </HTMLAlternativeTemplate>
</ASPNetFlash:Flash>
```

The flash file I'm using is version 9, but flash control tries to display version 10. Is there any problem? Otherwise, can you suggest the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example

```
 <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=7,0,19,0"
                                        width="200" height="100">
                                        <param name="movie" value="<% =swfFileName%>" />
                                        <param name="quality" value="high" />
                                        <embed src="<% =swfFileName%>" quality="high" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"
                                            type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="200" height="100"></embed>
```